# What does place/location return in the Facebook Graph for checkins?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to prototype some code, but the Facebook developer app has been down all weekend, leaving me without the ability to get an API key. So, for the sake of trying to complete some code without the ability to test, I'm trying to figure out what the location item of the place object is. Does it represent an address, lat/long coordinates, or something else?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to get an idea what it entails is to check the Open Graph representation of different places, i.e. https://graph.facebook.com/Place_ID.

Be careful, though - the object which represents in the fb profile the place where you live is not necessarily the object you can check in to (I hope this is clear enough to understand :))

For example, this request http://graph.facebook.com/108328065856235 returns

```
{
  "id": "108328065856235",
  "name": "York",
  "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net [...]",
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/York/108328065856235",
  "category": "City",
  "is_community_page": true,
  "description": "\u003cp>\u003cb>York\u003c/b> is a  [...]",
  "likes": 8839
}
```

But this http://graph.facebook.com/156983904330921 returns

```
{
   "id": "156983904330921",
   "name": "York",
   "picture": "http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/y2/r/pASyg-hBcD5.png",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/York/156983904330921",
   "category": "Local business",
   "is_community_page": true,
   "location": {
      "latitude": 53.955575003333,
      "longitude": -1.0468281266667
   },
   "checkins": 69,
   "likes": 6
}
```

Hope this helps!